# Alfresco AuthenticationService gives Error

Tags: php, alfresco, alfresco-share

I setup my alfresco SDK on my machine as shown in

https://code.google.com/p/alfresco-php-sdk/wiki/AlfrescoPHPLibraryInstallationInstructions

I changed the repository URL, UN, PW as guided in the page.

```
$repositoryUrl = "http://someip:8686/alfresco/api";
  $userName = "admin";
  $password = "admin";
```

When I try to go to http://localhost/alfresco/Examples/SimpleBrowse/index.php I get an error page.

At the end of the error page it says

Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://someip:8686/alfresco/api/AuthenticationService?wsdl' : failed to load external entity

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: It seems there's an [open issue](https://code.google.com/p/alfresco-php-sdk/issues/detail?id=22) which is likely to be similar

Answer (score 1):

which version of Alfresco do you use? In 4.2d+ the SOAP url has changed: try /alfresco/soapapi/AuthenticationService?wsdl

In 5.x Alfresco has removed the SOAP api. see http://richard.esplins.org/siwi/2014/11/03/important-changes-alfresco-50b/